# Shell script that switches screen off and on in one minute intervals?

Tags: linux, shell, lubuntu

I want to do a script that switches screen off and on in one minute intervals. Optional: When screen is off I am not allowed to force it back on.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    sleep 60 
    xscreensaver-command -lock
    sleep 60
    xscreensaver-command -deactivate
done
```